# Magento set custom page title and description for sitemap pages

Tags: magento

I am looking for a method to add custom page title and meta description to Magento defaults `catalog/seo_sitemap/category/` & `catalog/seo_sitemap/product/` pages.

I have done this before on the built-in contacts page by updating the contacts.xml file with:

```
    <reference name="head">     
        <action method="setDescription"><title>my description here</title></action>
        <action method="setTitle"><title>My title here</title></action>
    </reference>
```

This works absolutely fine. However, I currently do not know how I can apply this or a similar technique to the 2 pages I've outlined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do the same thing but apply it in the `catalog.xml` file.  You could also set up a `local.xml` with the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <catalog_seo_sitemap_category translate="label">
        <reference name="head">
             <action method="setDescription" module="catalog"><title>Custom description here</title></action>
             <action method="setTitle" module="catalog"><title>Custom Site Map here</title></action>
        </reference>
    </catalog_seo_sitemap_category>
</layout>
```

You can apply the same method to `catalog/seo_sitemap/product/`

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer @seanbreeden - I've seen to change the catalog.xml and implement some changes, now it works absolutely fine. Thanks again - truly appreciated.

Comment: Can we use this to take the title from `core_config_value` instead of hardcoding the string?